# Parcel & Svelte: Style tags with Sass?

Tags: sass, svelte, parcel

I'm using **Svelte** and **Parcel** along with **Sass** but can't get any scss within the `<style>` tags to render correctly. Below is an example of what I'm using.

```
<style lang="scss">
   $base-color: #c6538c;
   $border-dark: rgba($base-color, 0.88);

   .alert {
     border: 1px solid $border-dark;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok! For those looking for the solution, it's actually very easy, just took me a while to find it!

1. Create a `svelte.config.js` file at the root of your project
2. Install `svelte-preprocess` using npm or yarn
3. Use the below code in the `svelte.config.js` file

```
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');

module.exports = {
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
};
```

4. Add 'lang=scss' to your style tags like the below example

```
<style lang="scss">
  $base-color: #c6538c;
  $border-dark: rgba($base-color, 0.88);
  .container {
      border: 1px solid $border-dark;
   }
</style>
```

5. Enjoy writing **Sass** in your **Svelte** components!